# Android Dev Phone

Tags: android

Can you use any unlocked Motorola Droid phone for Android development? Say one you bought off of eBay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 'nearly' ( I say nearly just in case there are some exceptions that I'm not aware of) any phones for dev, just turn on "allow usb debugging n the settings.

Regarding the motorola droid, it works fine I have one at work and just plugged it in and launched my app.

for further reference, some phones are not recognized in the default settings of the android sdk (the htc legend for exemple), in those cases it is a simple matter of adding a line in your android sdk files (full procedure findable in 30 sec on google).

Comment: Just to confirm.... if I buy a Motorola Droid OR Droid X , I could use for development, by setting "allow usb debugging" regardless of whether its locked OR unlocked?

Comment: Our Motorola at work isn't unlocked and it works fine, the same for the htc magic and the htc N1. All in there factory settings. We had to unlock our N1 for a specific project, but whever it is locked or umlocked it doesn't prevent you from working with it.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, all you have to do is go under settings => development, and check the box to allow USB debugging.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can use any Android phone. You just have to enable USB debugging on the device and install the device driver on your computer.

Comment: Added note: The driver is required for Windows only.  http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

Answer (score 0):

The european counterpard (the Milestone) can be bought quite easily, not only from eBay but new too....I don't see why that wouldn't be the case for the Droid?

Comment: I think you misunderstand the question.  It has nothing to do with *whether* you can buy a phone, but rather *which one*, which phone is best to buy.

Comment: Ah. But the Motorola Droid is a phone, but did you mean which motorola Android phone to buy? Or what version of the motorola Droid? (are there versions?)

Answer (score 0):

Register for Android Market access in developer.android.com and you can buy the phone from the site.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the question. It has nothing to do with *whether* you can buy a phone, but rather *which one*, which phone is best to buy.

Comment: ohh. ok. understand. I have a motorola milestone2. The reason was simple. It has keyboard and touchscreen. So I could test for both.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by unlocked?  If you mean rooted, then you don't even need that.  My Motorola Droid works straight out of the box.  So, short answer: yes.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers!  I say unlocked because I want the phone for windows Android development and not for say registering on the verizon network. I don't need to make calls, just test an app....

Comment: @Mike: I believe the term for that(where I am, anyway) is "Not Activated".